# How to cascade State List for Selected Country using jQuery Ajax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a logic to display list of States on selection on Country.

I am using jQuery Ajax for this so that the State list gets updated instantly without reload of page.

I am stuck at place where I am getting the State list for selected Country but not aware to pass the jSon return type in view using ajax. Below is my code

View

```
<table>
<tbody>
<td>
    
@Html.DropDownList("countryVal", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countryVal, "Select Country", new { @id = "Country" })
    
</td>

<td>
<select id="state">Selet State

</select>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").text();

        alert(selectedCountry);

        if (selectedCountry != '') {

            alert("Working")

            $('#state').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/GetStates",
                data: { selectedCountry: selectedCountry },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(res, function (i, item) {
                            $('#state').append(new Option(item.stateName, item.stateId));
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        
    });
});  
</script>
```

Controller

public ActionResult DropDown()
{

```
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        ViewBag.countryVal = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "countryId", "CountryName");

        //ViewBag.stateName = new SelectList(db.States.ToList(),"stateId","stateName");

        //var test = ViewBag.countryVal;

        return View();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetStates(string selectedCountry)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        Country data = db.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryName == selectedCountry).FirstOrDefault();

        int id = data.countryId;
        List<State> stateList = db.States.Where(x => x.countryId == id).ToList();

        ViewBag.ID = id;

        ViewBag.SList = stateList;

        return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

        
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What's the version of asp.net you have used?

Comment: I am using VS 2017 17.2

Comment: You can double click your project name, and to see the SDK of asp.net.

Comment: If you put a `debugger;` in your ajax success, go to devtools and change the dropdown, does it get in there?

Comment: @QingGuo I have 15.9.51 version

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the list in the viewbag in Jayson

```
<select id="state">
</select>
```

Suppose state has Name and Id fields

```
$('#state').empty();
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "/Home/GetStates",
       data: { selectedCountry: selectedCountry },
       success: function (data) {
           if(data && data.length>0){
             $.each(res,function(i,item){
               $('#state').append(new Option(item.Name, item.Id));
             });
           }
         }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, but no results. Please see the new code above as per your suggestion.

Comment: Got it fixed, thank you. Have  updated the working code above.

Comment: Oh Yes,  how to show Select State value when no country is seleccted. If I add the following<select id="state">
              <option>Select State</option>
        </select>  and disable  $('#state').empty(); then it also brings the State for the previously selected Country. Any suggestion on this

Comment: No worries, got it working, working code posted above

Comment: Before calling the method, leave these two expression for the default value and put the value you want in the success body after the loop.$('#state').empty();$('#state').append(new Option('select a state', 0));

Comment: @RiyazShaikh My answer was also correct that you should do the details yourself

Comment: appreciate your help. Another issue, state is working but call to Country is not working. Updated the code in the Solution. Any hepl please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and working code for State but Country list not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var noCountry = $("#Country").children("option:selected").text();

    if (noCountry != '') {

        $('#state').append("<option value='0'>Selet State</option>");
    }

    $("#Country").change(function () {


        debugger;

        var selkt = noCountry;

        var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").text();


        //alert(selectedCountry);
        $('#state').empty();

        $('#state').append("<option value='0'>Selet State</option>");


        if (selectedCountry != '') {

            //alert("Working")


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/GetStates",
                data: { selectedCountry: selectedCountry },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#state').append(new Option(item.stateName, item.stateId));
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }


    });


    $('#cityList').append("<option value='0'>Select City</option>").text();

    $('#state').change(function () {


        var stateSelected = $('#state').children("option:selected").text();

        if (stateSelected != 'Selet State' | stateSelected != '') {
            //debugger;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Demo/GetCity",
                data: { stateSelected: stateSelected },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, items) {

                            $('#cityList').append(new Option(items.cityName, items.cityId));

                        });
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

So, helped adding a debugger and identify the breaking point.